# Contracting mouth muscles as reaction to taking in specific food items

Tags: human-physiology, muscles

When eating very specific food items, especially confectionery like (salty) liquorice, (it feels as if) the muscles of my mouth contract, right when it hits my tongue.

Does anyone know why this happens?

The process is similar to experiencing relatively high levels of sourness - suggesting it is a similar reaction - but, as far as I know, there is, apart from the [glycyrrhizic acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glycyrrhizin) in the liquorice plant, not a lot of acid in this type of confectionery. I imagine other possible causes could be sugar substitutes like steviol or Maltitol.